# Text Fields Acceptable in SQL Loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Are there any reserved text characters in SQL Loader ?
Any special characters like &,_" etc which cannot be loaded in Oracle table columns ?

My file column seperator is a pipe {|} character and I will  escape to accept this too in my text columns but are there any other reserved characters which I cannot use in the data fields to be interfaced ?

Answer (score 0):

There are none, as far as I can tell.

However, I'd suggest you to choose delimiters wisely because if text you're loading contains delimiters, you'll have problems in figuring out whether e.g. a pipe sign is a delimiter, or part of text to be loaded.

If you can prepare input data so that values are *optionally enclosed* into double quotes, you'd be able to avoid such problems. However, why having it complicated if it can be simple?